# Get dpi value from onTouch event on ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, dpi

I would like to have the dpi value, if the user taps the **imageview** on my activity.

at the moment i have set an **onTouchListener**, but with this listener i only get the "event.getX/Y" pixel values..

is there any way to get the dpi value? maybe something like a converter px->dpi?

EDIT:

```
// Converting dips to pixels
float dips = 20.0f;
float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = Math.round(dips * scale);

// Converting pixels to dips
int pixels = 15;
float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float dips = pixels / scale;
```

Comment: think so, yes. is there a way?

Comment: I'm not convinced.  First, "dpi" stands for "dots per inch."  DPI does not change depending on where you click on the screen--it is the screen's resolution.  "DIP" stands for density-independent pixels, which I'm assuming, is what you want.  Second, http://tinyurl.com/5wlltf6 .  The first 3 links on the list tell you how to do it, including giving you a link to the Android Developer's website where they also tell you how to do it.  This question has been asked many times before.

Comment: i googled before.. but didnt find something i need. maybe because i searched dpi instead of DIP. thanks. :)